# Settimeout just after a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a removeClass function work right after another function ends, so I have this script to call a fittocontainer:

```
    function fittocontainer(){
        $('.fittocontainer').fittocontainer()
    }
```

And I want that after the function 'fittocontainer' ends, apply this function:

```
            setTimeout ( function(){
                $('#footer').removeClass("active");
            })
```

How can I integrate the setTimeout function with the 'fittocontainer()' to work after it has just ended?

Comment: Your `setTimeout()` needs a time duration.  What's the problem with just calling `setTimeout()` right after you call `fittocontainer()`?

Comment: I doubt your `.fittocontainer()` method is asynchronous

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is fittocontainer a function that you made? If so, and it is asynchronous, you will have to add a callback like:

```
function fittocontainer (cb) {
  //do some stuff
  cb();
}
```

Then you can call it passing a function or even an anonymous function like:

```
fittocontainer(function () {
  // do stuff afterwards
});
```

If this function is updating the DOM it is most likely asynchronous. Using a timeout to try and execute code after an async method is very dangerous and should never be done.

If it is synchronous, you can simply call a function on the next line and know that it will execute after fittocontainer is complete.

Also remember that you need a timeout on the setTimeout like:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#footer').removeClass("active");
}, 1000);
```

that is a timeout of 1 second

Comment: yeah it's a function I made

Comment: Ok awesome, then you can pass a callback as an argument to that function and have it invoked at the end of your function just like my first example

Answer (score 3):

setTimeout() is about time (minutes, seconds), if you only want to execute that function at the end, you could just call it, or you could use a [callback](http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/) function:

```
function fittocontainer(callback){
  $('.fittocontainer').fittocontainer();
  callback();
}
```

and then call fittocontainer:

```
fittocontainer(function(){
  $('#footer').removeClass("active");
});
```

Comment: I was just about to make the same point...setting a timeout of 1 second seems unnecessary in this case.